# What's the meaning of "logical" in the definition of reasoning?

Tags: word-meaning, definition

*Reasoning* such as:

- What is the reasoning behind this decision?, and
- This line of reasoning is faulty.

is defined on [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reasoning?q=reasoning) as:

- the process of thinking about things in a logical way; opinions and ideas that are based on logical thinking

What does *logical* mean in this definition? Does it mean (from [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/logical_1?q=%20logical%20)):

1. (of an action, event, etc.) seeming natural, reasonable or sensible. or
2. following or able to follow the rules of logic in which ideas or facts are based on other true ideas or facts